# How to migrate tf.compat.v1.variable_scope() to TF2

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I need to convert the following model to TF2. `get_outputs()` applies several convolution layers, then flat and dense layers and produces some outputs.

```
with tf.compat.v1.variable_scope(scope_name, reuse=tf.compat.v1.AUTO_REUSE):
    outputs = get_outputs()
```

The following lines apply an exponential moving average to the trainable variables.

```
params = tf.compat.v1.trainable_variables(scope_name)
ema = tf.train.ExponentialMovingAverage(alpha)
ema_apply_op = ema.apply(params)


def custom_getter(getter, *args, **kwargs):
    return ema.average(getter(*args, **kwargs))
```

This is an identical model which outputs the same outputs after somehow using the custom getter defined above.

```
with tf.compat.v1.variable_scope(
        scope_name, reuse=True, custom_getter=custom_getter
):
    avg_outputs = get_outputs()
```

And after each training iteration:

```
with tf.control_dependencies([opt_op]):  # opt_op being the result of optimizer.apply_gradients()
    grouped = tf.group(ema_apply_op)
```

And then `grouped` is run in the default session. I need some way to convert this to TF2. I tried the following and I'm not sure whether this works or not, for some reason the translated to TF2 model (keras) does not converge. I'm trying to find out why by eliminating potential sources causing the issue.

```
model = create_keras_model()  # Keras model, results in the same outputs by TF1 model.
avg_model = create_keras_model()  # Identical model
```

And after each training iteration, I do the following:

```
avg_weights = []

for w1, w2 in zip(model.trainable_variables, avg_model.trainable_variables):
    avg_weights.append(alpha * w2 + (1 - decay) * w1)
avg_model.set_weights(avg_weights)
```

Due to model convergence issues, I cannot determine whether this works or not. I also tried replicating the same steps using `tf.train.ExponentialMovingAverage` however, it doesn't do anything in TF2. When `ema.apply()` and `ema.average()` are called on the training variables, nothing happens, their values remain unchanged.

Comment: Try tf_upgrade_v2 script to upgrade from TF V1 code To TF V2. For more information visit [this site](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/upgrade). Thanks!

Comment: @TFer I already fixed the problem by converting to equivalent keras semantics, thanks. To your information, `tf_upgrade_v2` just replaces every call to TF1-only compatible stuff to `tf.compat.v1.some_tf1_func()` many of which won't work unless you explicitly disable eager execution, which is the same as writing TF1 code in the first place. So it's you who will eventually do the heavy lifting.